# Problems to run git push

Tags: github

I've been trying to run the command

git push -u origin master,

but what I get is this:

fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository

fatal: could not read from remote repository

Answer (score 0):

you can type from within your repo:

```
git remote -v
```

And see if there is any remote named 'origin' listed in it.

If not, if that remote (which is created by default when cloning a repo) is missing, you can add it again:

```
git remote add origin url/to/your/fork
```